# How do I find resolved JIRA issues in the CURRENT week (Monday to Friday)

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I want to find all the issues resolved in current week.
We are using JIRA web ui. I do see a way to specify "From" and "To" dates in JIRA Filter customization for resolution field. 
I am wondering what the right syntax is to specify the from date is Monday of current week.

The way I like to use this filter is to put this in a Dashboard and look at it each day at the end how we are doing with bug fixing in the current week.

Thanks
Video guy

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best you can do in Jira 4.1.1 is to get all issues resolved in the last 7 days from now:
`resolutiondate >= "-7d"`

Or create a filter for each day of the week. For example filter 'Issues resolved in a week (Wednesday)" will be `resolutiondate >= "-3d"`. And filter 'Issues resolved in a week (Friday)" will be `resolutiondate >= "-5d"`

Starting from Jira 4.3 you can use [startOfWeek()](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-startOfWeek) function - `resolutiondate > startOfWeek()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an advanced issue search using the format:

```
resolutiondate >= "2012-10-14" and resolutiondate <= "2012-10-20"
```

Comment: Then you have to keep changing the filter every week. I tried "resolved >= currentDayOfWeek()", but currentDayOfWeek() is not recognized in the JIRA version we have (JIRA 4.1.1).